# Matlab integral function & function handles in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, integral, function-handle

'Outliers.m' is called from a higher level .m file. The variables are all defined in the higher level file, and set as globals for access by Outliers.m. The purpose of the code is to identify outliers using Chauvenets Criterion, and for this, I have to calculate the integral of the guassian distribution, using the Integral function and function handles. The code works and gives sensible values when I enter specific variables as a test, but I cannot get it to work in a loop. My data set is comprised of 7 individual samples, each 1x30, all of which need to be analyzed. I have had various errors, read through the guidance on Integral and function handles, but cannot seem to find the solution...Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.... Here is my code:

```
n = 7
for x = 1:n
    for y = 1:30
    z(x,y) = abs((cc(x,y) - mastercc(1,y))/masterccstd(1,y));
    xmax(x,y) = mastercc(1,y)+z(x,y)*masterccstd(1,y);
    xmin(x,y) = mastercc(1,y)-z(x,y)*masterccstd(1,y);
    p(x,y) = 1/(masterccstd(1,y)*(sqrt(2*pi)));

    fun(x,y)= @(x,y,z) (exp(-1/2)*z(x,y).^2);
    q(x,y) = integral(fun(x,y),xmin(x,y),xmax(x,y),'ArrayValued',true);

    pq(x,y) = p(x,y)*q(x,y); % probability
    value(x,y) = n*(1/pq(x,y));
    count(x,y) = logical(value(x,y) <0.5);
    badbins(x)=sum(count(x,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your question? If you encounter an error message, please state the exact message, on which line it occurs, and describe the relevant variables.

Comment: Hi Denis - sorry, forgot to put the error! Here it is:                                                                 Error using @(x,y,z)(exp(-1/2).*z(x,y).^2)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in outliers (line 30)
    q(x,y) = integral(fun(x,y),xmin(x,y),xmax(x,y),'ArrayValued',true);

Error in mastercal_diameters (line 46)
outliers

Comment: Why do you have the `'ArrayValued'` option turned on and set to `true`? From what I can see, the output of your function `fun` is a scalar, no? But from your comment below it looks like you may not even be using this code. Are you defining, passing in, and calling your function handle properly?: `fun = @(z)exp(-1/2)*z.^2;` `q(x,y) = integral(fun(z(x,y)),xmin(x,y),xmax(x,y));`.

Comment: @horchler - the outcome should be a 7x30 double, as I need the probability of each data point from the 7x30 double called 'cc'. I have run the above original code, but replacing your suggested 2 lines of code and get a new error: "Error using integral (line 83)
First input argument must be a function handle.

Error in outliers (line 30)
    q(x,y) = integral(fun(z(x,y)),xmin(x,y),xmax(x,y));" Interestingly, 'fun' DOES show up as a function handle in the workspace (confirmed by: isa(fun,'function_handle') = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the loop problem, courtesy Andrei Bobrov via Matlab Central, link below:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103958#comment_177000

NB: Please note the code is not complete for the purpose I explained in the problem description, but it does solve the Loop error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your error is caused by an invald function definition.

If you try it like this it should work:

```
fun = @(x,y,z) (exp(-1/2)*z(x,y).^2)
```

Now it can be called like this for example:

```
fun(1,2,magic(4))
```

Comment: I replaced the function handle with:

 fun = @(x,y,z) (exp(-1/2)*z(x,y).^2);

and the integral function with:

 q(x,y) = integral(fun(x,y,z),xmin(x,y),xmax(x,y),'ArrayValued',true);
    
And it has come up with the same error.....

Comment: @GingerMonster Please run it with `dbstop if error` and describe which variables you are trying to input on the line where the code stops.

Comment: The error stops at the 'integral' line, and refers back to the functionhandle ‘fun’. The variables at this point are :
   x = 1
   y = 1
   z = 0.2502
   xmax = 1.9428
   xmin = 1.9104
 
If it helps, here is the same code but with no loops, and the variables replaced with constants:

    n = 7;    
    z = abs(4.3794 - 1)/1;
    xmax = 1+z*1;
    xmin = 1-z*1;
    p = 1/(1*2.5066);
    fun = @(z) exp(-1/2*z.^2);
    q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax);
    pq = p*q;
    value = 6*1/pq;
    count = logical(value <0.5);
    badbins=sum(count);

Comment: @GingerMonster The function you post in this comment runs without problems for me. If that is not the case for you please restart matlab and try again. -- I think you may be asking `integral` to do something it cant. Please try treading `help integral`, then start with a small problem and build up from there.

Comment: just to confirm, re:the code which you can run without problems, was it the code with or without the loop? I have restarted matlab and no joy (running in the loop). I have already read through the Help (several times!) on Integral and FunctionHandles. Thanks for your help and time thus far - hopefully the solution will present itself soon!